# Call a method for all objects of a certain type

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I have a list of objects that were instantiated from different classes. I want to call a certain method on all objects of a certain class in that list.  I feel that the way I found is not very elegant and there may be a better one.

Currently, I do it like this:

```
def execute(fn, classname, objlist):
    '''
    The function that iterates over all objects, 
    finds the fitting ones, and executes the chosen "fn"
    '''
    for obj in objlist:
        # Checks for the class from which the object was instantiated
        if type(obj) is classname:
            # Execute the function.
            fn(obj)

class C():
    def myfn(self):
        print("foo")

class D():
    def otherfn(self):
        print("bar")

objlist = []

objlist.append(C())
objlist.append(D())

execute(C.myfn, C, objlist)
execute(D.otherfn, D, objlist)
```

Output is:

```
foo
bar
```

Is there a better way?

**Edit: For clarification of the problem**

I will try to illustrate the problem in a simple way, and I hope that I do not overwhelm you with details.

I have an application that interfaces with ethernet connected embedded stations on my network. Each of these stations is represented by a different class, and each class provides different functionality for controlling this station.

Firstly, a scan has to be performed, so that I know, which stations are actually available on the network. Therefore, a basic "Station" object is created and "scan" is called. A scan is a request that expects an answer from the station. If there is an answer, it will specify the exact type of the connected station.

Secondly, the basic station needs to be extended by the "mode" that was just found out by that first scanning step. The "Basic" mode is replaced by the specific mode that the station is in. The "Basic" mode just allows for this scanning that was just performed.

This is the actual basic station class. __LinkUI holds some information about things that were typed into a user interface, like IP address ranges and ports:

```
class Station(__LinkUI):
    '''
    Generic class for creating a station. This is used first for
    stations that have no known type yet
    '''
    def __init__(self, ip, storage):
        super().__init__(storage)

        # IP Address of this station
        self.ip = ip

        # The handling object for the TCP connection to this station
        self.handler = Handler(self.storage.network.confport, self.pool)

        # Last response value to a request message
        self.response = None

        # mode of this station. This is an object that details 
        # some functions and variables for controlling a certain 
        # type of station. "Basic" is the default mode with 
        # no special functions
        self.mode = Basic(self)

        # Hardware architecture of a station, like DDS/PLL
        self.architecture = None
```

This is an example of a "mode" class, like "Boot", which represents a station that is in bootloader mode. This "mode" extends the functionality of the "Station" object.

```
class Boot(__Mode):
    '''
    Extends a station by the boot mode
    '''
    def __init__(self, station):
        self.name = "Boot"
        super().__init__(self, station)

        # The interface for using the flash mode of the boot station
        self.flashInterface = FlashInterface(station)
        self.healthInterface = HealthInterface(station)

    def flash(self, callback, data):
        self.flashInterface.flash(callback, data)

    def run(self, callback):
        self.flashInterface.run(callback)
```

__Mode is the base class that connects some variables and generates a "Messenger" that is used to generate the actual raw messages that are sent to stations:

```
class __Mode():
    '''
    Base class for different station modes (Boot, Rx, Tx, Central)
    '''
    def __init__(self, child, station):
        # Generate a messenger object for this kind of station
        self.messenger = GetMessenger(child)

        # Connect variables
        self.station = station
        station.mode = child
        station.name = child.name
        station.messenger = child.messenger
```

I made so-called "Interfaces" that attach to "Mode" objects and offer functionality to control a station in a certain way. I can connect multiple interfaces to one station, so it gains the functions of all of them.

In conclusion, stations can be very different and I am not sure if polymorphism is applicable. Methods will not have the same names, functionality or parameters.

Sorry, if this lacks information or offers too much of it.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, why not just use polymorphism?

Comment: This does look like a polymorphism problem, but to be sure we'd need to know what your classes actually are. Could you edit your question to show your actual classes instead of dummies?

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be anything wrong with this approach to me. It’s concise and does what you want it to. You could do it with the `map` function and a list comprehension: `map(fn, [obj for obj in objlist if type(obj) is classname]`. The problem with that is you’re building a list from the list comprehension and then iterating over it with `map`, so you’re effectively iterating twice, whereas your solution only loops once.

Comment: I extended the question now. You might be right, but I prefer not to pass the "Class", as well as the "method". I would rather pass just "Class.method" and "execute()" figures out, which class "method" belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to implemente all possible operations (as no-op) in the base `Mode` class so you can just call whatever operation without worrying about the current mode of an object.

Another solution is to use `getattr()` and the method name:

```
def execute(objlist, methodname, *args, **kw):
    for obj in objlist:
        method = getattr(obj, methodname, None)
        if method:
            method(*args, **kw)
```

FWIW, what you have here with your `Mode` classes is actually an incomplete "State" pattern. [You may want to read about it...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your test to know whether an object belong to a class is too restrictive  and does not correctly process sub-types. For example, it I add this to your code:

```
class E(C):
   pass

objlist.append(E())
```

`objlist` now contains one instance of C, one of D and one of E. But the E instance is also a C by inheritance, so I would expect the output of:

```
execute(C.myfn, C, objlist)
```

to be:

```
foo
foo
```

So I would rewrite your function:

```
def execute(fn, classname, objlist):
    '''
    The function that iterates over all objects, 
    finds the fitting ones, and executes the chosen "fn"
    '''
    for obj in objlist:
        # Checks for the class from which the object was instantiated
        if isinstance(obj, classname):
            # Execute the function.
            fn(obj)
```